# Cant get list of definitions from a website using a for loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

New to python here. I'm trying to get the word of the day along with the definitions and the "did you know?" section from here https://www.merriam-webster.com/word-of-the-day

Any idea what I'm missing?

So far all I can get is the following:

```
C:\Users\Think\PycharmProjects\wotd\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Think/PycharmProjects/wotd/wotd.py
loon
Definition
1 : lout, idler
```

loon is the word and the lines after is the first definition only. There are 3 more but I cant get them with this method.

Thank you for any guidance

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

sauce = requests.get('https://www.merriam-webster.com/word-of-the-day').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

article = soup.find('article')

word = article.find('div', class_='word-and-pronunciation').h1.text
definition = article.find('div', class_='wod-definition-container').h2.text

print(word)
print(definition)

for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    defin = article.find('div', class_='wod-definition-container').p.text
    print(defin)
```

Answer (score 0):

`article.find('div', class_='wod-definition-container').p.text` returns just fist

. Try like this.

```
for s in soup.find_all('article')[0].find('div', class_='wod-definition-container').find_all('p'):
    print(s.text)
```

Comment: Thank you shimo, that worked and I see why :)  The output now gives me all the definitions along with the text after "did you know?" and some other irrelevant text. How do I limit how far down the for loop can go if I only want the definitions? Sometimes there are 2 definitions and sometimes 5. Is there a way to make it stop at the last definition?

Comment: I'm not sure the structure of page well, but If I do, like check `if str(num) + " : "  in s.text` , and `num += 1` in each for loop.